# Variance of X vs Variance of a binary function of X

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, variance

Let $X$ be a random variable in $[0, 1]$ and $m$ its median such that $P(X \le m) = P(X \ge m)$.

Define $\beta(X)$ as
$$\beta (x) = 
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\begin{align*}
1&,\space X \ge m; \\ 
0&,\space otherwise.
\end{align*}
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
(a) Is it true that $Var(X) \le Var(\beta(X))$?

(b) What if $X$ is continuous?

**Where I got stuck:** If $X$ is a discrete random variable, $\beta(X)$ is just Bernoulli with $p = 0.5$ and $Var(\beta(X)) = 0.25$. I couldn't come up with any discrete X whose variance is bigger than that. Tried simple Bernoulli; $X = 0.5^{i-1}$ with $p(x_{i})=0.5^i$. All variances are smaller than or equal to 0.25. However, I couldn't come up with a formal proof either.

Reasoning for (b) will depend on the proof/counterexample with (a) I guess.

Please help!

P.S. First time poster hear. Apologies if something's wrong with my post

Comment: Think of $X$ as a uniform distribution on $\{0,\frac12,1\}$.  $m = \frac12$, but $P(X \le m) = P(X \ge m) = \frac23$.

Comment: Good first question and interesting problem! Where did you find it?

Comment: @yurnero Thank you. This problem is from a past admission exam to a Russian data science school (link in Russian)
https://efiminem.github.io/supershad/27-05-2017/

Comment: @GNUSupporter Thanks for the idea! Still I got $Var(X) \le Var(\beta(X))$:
$$E(X) = 1/2, \space E(\beta(X)) = 2/3$$
$$E(X^2) = 5/12, \space E(\beta(X)^2) = 2/3$$
$$Var(X) = E(X^2)-E^2(X) = 5/12 - 1/4 = 2/12$$
$$Var(\beta(X)) = E(\beta(X)^2)-E^2(\beta(X)) = 2/9 > 2/12$$
Maybe I screwed up computations, but upon a second check I couldn't find errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incomplete answer / Possible approach:

First of all if $P(X=m) = p = 0$ then (regardless of whether $X$ is otherwise continuous) the answer by @GNUSupporter suffices to show that $Var(X) \le {1 \over 4} = Var(\beta(X))$.

So for the rest assume $P(X=m) = p > 0$.  I *think* (a) is true even for this case.  (Further I *think* this is due to the (IMHO) quite restrictive *definition* of median in the OP - see my comments at the end.)

Define a new random variable $Y$ s.t.

- $X < m \implies Y = 0$ (this happens with probability $q = {1-p \over 2}$)
- $X = m \implies Y = m$ (this happens with probability $p$)
- $X > m \implies Y = 1$ (this happens with probability $q = {1-p \over 2}$)

The following chain shows that $Var(Y) \le Var(\beta(X))$:

$Var(Y) = E[Y^2] - E[Y]^2 = (p m^2 + q) - (pm + q)^2 $

$\quad = p m^2 + q - (p^2 m^2 + 2pqm + q^2)$

$\quad = m^2 p (1-p) - 2pqm + q(1-q) $

$\quad = 2pq m^2 - 2pq m + q (1-q) \quad \quad \text{...because $(1-p)= 2q$}$

$\quad = 2pq m(m-1) + q(1-q) $

$\quad \le q(1-q) \quad \quad \text{...because $(m-1)\le 0$}$

$\quad = P(X < m)P(X \ge m) = Var(\beta(X))$

Therefore, all that remains is to show that $Var(X) \le Var(Y)$.  This *ought* to be true from a "moment of inertia" perspective, as we are simply "pushing" the mass on both sides of $m$ to the extreme values of $0, 1$.  However, I was not able to prove this.  :(

---

Further comment: I was very surprised by the above result (if indeed the proof can be completed, i.e. $Var(X) \le Var(Y)$).  I now think the reason is that the *definition* of median in the OP is quite restrictive.

E.g., if $X \in \{0, \epsilon, 1\}$ with probabilities $(0.02, 0.49, 0.49)$ then the median as defined in the OP does not exist.

Instead, lets consider a less restrictive definition: $m'$ is a newmedian if $P(X \ge m') \ge {1\over 2}$ and $P(X \le m') \ge {1 \over 2}$.  Then in the example above the newmedian is $\epsilon$.  And this finally is a valid "counterexample" when $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+$:

- $X \rightarrow Bern(0.49)$
- $Var(X) \rightarrow (0.51)(0.49) \approx {1 \over 4}$
- $\beta(X)$ (redefined using newmedian) $\rightarrow Bern(0.98)$
- $Var(\beta(X)) \rightarrow (0.98)(0.02) \approx 0.02 < Var(X)$

Answer (score 4):

$$Var(\beta(X)) = E[1_{\{X \ge m\}}^2] - E[1_{\{X \ge m\}}]^2 = \cdots = P(X \ge m) P(X<m)$$

If $X$ is continuous, then $P(X = x) = 0$ for all $x$.
$$Var(\beta(X)) = \cdots = P(X \ge m) P(X<m) = \frac14$$
Note that $0 \le X \le 1$, so $0 \le X^2 \le X \le 1$.
$$Var(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2 \le E[X] - E[X]^2 \le E[X] (1 - E[X]) \le \frac14$$
The last inequality can be proved using [a.m.-g.m.-inequality](/questions/tagged/a.m.-g.m.-inequality) or [quadratics](/questions/tagged/quadratics).

Comment: Can you please explain why $Var(\beta(X)) = P(X \ge m)P(X < M)$?

Comment: I've edited my posts.  Please see.

Comment: Now I understand, thank you. Can you please guide me on the discrete part as well? I took your example of $X$ uniform on $\{0, \space 1/2, \space 1\}$ but got stuck with $Var(X) = 2/12 < 2/9 = Var(\beta(X))$. Do you think I made a mistake somewhere?

Comment: My proposed example failed.  I'm still think this.

Comment: This may be useful: any $X$ that is $0$ with prob. $\frac{1}{2}-p$, $\frac{1}{2}$ with $2p$, and $1$ with prob. $\frac{1}{2}-p$ for $p\leq\frac{1}{2}$ * fails * as a counter example to (a). GNU's earlier proposal is a particular case with $p=\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: @yurnero Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Right, same conclusion holds true for $X$ uniform on $\{0, y, 1\}$, $0 < y < 1$